How to Handle Custom Fixed Operations in PyTorch with External Libraries (e.g., OpenCV) and Backpropagate Gradients?
I'm working on a PyTorch project where I need to train a neural network that uses a custom FIXED operation from a third-party library (specifically, OpenCV). This operation modifies the input data and its output is then used to calculate the loss with respect to the target data.
The issue is that OpenCV only works with NumPy arrays, which means I need to convert my PyTorch tensors to NumPy (forcing the computation onto the CPU). Doing so breaks PyTorch's computational graph, making it impossible to use loss.backward() to automatically compute the gradients.
Moreover, I’m struggling to figure out how to implement a custom autograd function with a proper backward pass to account for this kind of scenario. I've looked into the literature and found no clear solution for handling this issue in a reusable way.
My questions are:

How can I maintain gradient flow when using third-party libraries
like OpenCV,which require converting tensors to NumPy (and therefore break the computational graph)?
If I need to implement a custom autograd function, how can I correctly calculate the backward pass when the custom operation is non-differentiable or uses a fixed transformation?
Are there any existing best practices or general solutions to this problem?

This is the scheme:


Your pytorch model has to be end to end differentiable. You can try write a custom backward method to handle operations outside the computational graph, but I guarantee you this is more trouble than it's worth. You're better off finding a different approach
